# How to tell when Cocoa MainMenu controls have been loaded

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

How can I tell when all of the MainMenu nib controls (primarily the main window) have been loaded?  I want to display a sheet on top of the main window at launch, but when I put call beginSheet inside of awakeFromNib, I get an error because no windows have been displayed yet:  : kCGErrorIllegalArgument: _CGSFindSharedWindow: WID -1

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

For this type of action, I'd suggest using the [-applicationDidFinishLaunching](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) delegate method. You'll implement this in your application delegate. Start the sheet from there and you're guaranteed that MainMenu.nib/xib is loaded by then.